# VS 2012 Apply Styles and Manage Styles menu options are missing

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I've got a project that has a windows service, a few console apps and now a MVC web interface.  Everything is written in C#.

I'm to the point in modifying the default CSS template but need a visual tool to do so.  In researching this I found that there is supposed to be a menu option under View called "Apply Styles" that appears to be a visual CSS editor; or at least it will let me see what I'm doing.  However, when I go to find that menu option it's not there.  I've tried selecting the .CSHTML file, the CSS file and even the .cs file and checking the view menu and it's just not showing.

I then reset the interface to see if that had anything to do with it and when I did that it came back up with what type of development I'm doing.  I'm wondering if the reason I'm not seeing the Apply Styles option is because I'm in C# development and not web development in visual studio.  I hope that's not the case as the majority of my work right now is WPF, Form, or console work; not web.

Does anyone know how to get this menu option to show?

thanks!

BTW, this is the Microsoft link I'm going off of: [working with css overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398931.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply Styles and Manage Styles are powered by the Web Forms designer in VS.  In order to use them, you need to be using the designer - which isn't available for CSHTML files.

The team has instead been investing much more in improvements to the CSS editor and Page Inspector.  These are probably more valuable to you if you're using MVC anyways.